# TypeError: THREE.FileLoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

I'm having trouble getting a framework using three.js to work for an assignment. I've cloned [this repository](https://github.com/CIS700-Procedural-Graphics/Project2-Toolbox-Functions) and used `npm install` to download the dependencies. When I run the server and load the page I get `TypeError: THREE.FileLoader is not a constructor`.

This seems to be because there is no FileLoader file but I don't know how to fix the issue - I tried deleting the contents of `node_module/three` and replacing it with the up-to-date [three.js repository](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js), but that gave me `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "three"`.

I don't know why running `npm install` didn't give me the updated version of three.js and gave me code that won't run. How do I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileLoader is not available using `"three": "0.82.1"`
Just update your `three.js` version to `"three": "^0.84.0"` in the `package.json` and run `npm i` once again